# Linux packet processing bypass kernel protocol stack

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, kernel-module

I want to process packets in my own logic by developing a kernel module.

To be more specific, for the packets sent to `enp0s3`, I want to remove its ethernet header and send it to `tap1`. `tap1` is a tap device.

The problem is: I can't find any packet at `tap1` by using Wireshark.

`dev_queue_xmit` return code is 2.

I'm a noob about Linux kernel programming, I need some help!

Here is my code:

```
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/inet.h>
#include <net/net_namespace.h>
#include <linux/skbuff.h>

#define NIPQUAD(addr) \
  ((unsigned char *)&addr)[0], \
  ((unsigned char *)&addr)[1], \
  ((unsigned char *)&addr)[2], \
  ((unsigned char *)&addr)[3]

struct net_device *dev;
/**
 * Hook function to be called.
 * We modify the packet's src IP.
 */
rx_handler_result_t my_hookfn(struct sk_buff **skb)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "hook!\n");

    struct sk_buff *sb=*skb;

    /* remove ethernet header code here*/

    // forward to tap1
    struct net_device *go = dev_get_by_name(&init_net, "tap1");
    if (go == NULL) 
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "tap1 not find \n");
        return -1;
    }

    sb->dev = go;

    int status = dev_queue_xmit(sb);
    printk(KERN_INFO "forward status is %d\n", status);


    return RX_HANDLER_CONSUMED;
}
int init_module()
{
    int ret;

    dev = dev_get_by_name(&init_net, "enp0s3");

    if (dev == NULL) 
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "enp0s3 not find \n");
        return -1;
    }

    ret = netdev_rx_handler_register(dev, my_hookfn, NULL);

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "module is NOT loaded into the kernel\n");    
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "module IS loaded into the kernel\n");      
        return 0;
    }
}

void cleanup_module()
{
    netdev_rx_handler_unregister(dev);
    printk(KERN_INFO "module has been unloaded\n");  
}

MODULE_AUTHOR("lhy");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? Show us some code.

Comment: @red0ct Hi, I used `netdev_rx_handler_register` function to achieve my own packet receive processing logic. Here is the code: `netdev_rx_handler_register(dev, my_hookfn, NULL);`

Comment: But I don't know how to forward the packet to a specific NIC after my process. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you implement *"your own packet receive processing logic"*? Is it kernel module or kernel patch or whatever? Show some code or edit your question with some sufficient explanation (read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Your "specific" problem is absolutely unclear. You said that you *"don't know how to forward the packet"*, so is the second problem with L2-header still relevant? Edit your question please.

Comment: @red0ct Sorry, this is my first time to ask questions here. I have updated my question. Thank you for your patience.